# Why doesn't React Dev Tools display properties called "name"?

Tags: javascript, class, react-devtools

I have the following TypeScript object in a React project:

```
class ExampleClass {
    name: string;
    name2: string;
    favouriteThing: string;


    constructor(name: string, favouriteThing: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.name2 = name;
        this.favouriteThing = favouriteThing;
    }
}
```

When viewing this object as part of a hook or prop in React Dev Tools, this is how it's displayed:

[React Dev Tools screenshot displaying 2 ExampleClass objects with the properties "name2" and "favouriteThing"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB4yK.png)

Only the the properties `name2` and `favouriteThing` are displayed.

I'm able to see that `name` does still exist on the object by outputting it to the console:

[Console output displaying 2 objects with the properties "name", "name2", and "favouriteThing"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUBO6.png)

I would expect `name` to be displayed along with the other properties in React Dev Tools. Is there something special/reserved about a property called `name`? Is there a reason why `name` is not displayed?